# Python Transferring files between two zipfiles

Tags: python, transfer, zip

I've been trying to use the built-in python zipfiles module to manipulate some .zip files on windows, I wish to use them to store a number of files related to the current project in a program. The problem comes when I load the files from the zip and then wish to re-save them into a new, different zip file:

```
import zipfile
zp = zipfile.ZipFile(r"first.zip",mode='r')
myfile = zp.open(r"stored_file.txt",mode='r')

### Do something, then want to save again ###

zp2 = zipfile.ZipFile(r"second.zip",mode='w')

#Doesn't work, as myfile isn't a real file:
zp2.write(myfile)
#Doesn't work, as the path can't be resolved:
zp2.write(os.path.join(zp.filename,myfile.name))
#The following works... as long as you haven't called read()
#since .seek(0) doesn't work for ZipExtFile
zp2.writestr(myfile.name,myfile.read())
```

I could, of course, extract the files to somewhere and then re-add them to the new zip that way, but it would be clunky and require a lot of cleanup (and creating a lot of temporary files).

Equally I could keep track of the original zip file and use the writestr method by re-opening the file, but I was hoping to avoid it. I just wondered if there was a better way around this problem; it means I'll have to have code that determines whether the file originally came from a zip or not as well and handle it differently if it did.

Edit: If anyone else has the final problem with seek(0) not working on ZipExtFile, it is possible to use an io.StringIO class to hold the result of str(myfile.read()), which is then seekable. It means I have to keep the files loaded in memory, though, so I'm going to go with keeping track of the zipfile and transferring them only when I need them.

Comment: Unfortunately because of the nature of zip files, I don't think there is another way other than extracting and rewriting into a new file. See http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/Replacing-files-in-a-zip-archive-td1558633.html for some discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, vikramls, interesting link.